# Html table fixed vertical scroll

Tags: html, scroll, css-tables, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I have a table with a large amount of columns and rows, the table is in a div with a fixed size, so I have a horizontal and vertical scrolling.

The vertical scroll is only displayed after you scroll the the last column.

Is there any way to make the vertical scroll bar fixed so its always displayed, and not only when you scroll to the end?

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 2):

I tell you to use property `overflow-y:auto` instead of `overflow-y:scroll`. 
To get to know more and how to use with example follow the [link](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow-y:scroll` in css. If you're not familiar with css, the easiest way is to do it like this:

```
<table style="overflow-y:scroll">
```

For horizontal scrolling, use `overflow-x` instead.

See **[this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)** for all possible overflow values.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I found out a solution.

Keep your table inside a div and give that div the following css

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and your css would be

```
.wrapper{width: 100%; max-width: 700px; max-height: 400px; margin: 30px auto; overflow: auto; padding: 0 15px;}
```